# Visual Studio Performance Analyzer crashing

Tags: f#

I have a relatively small F# app (< 400K) built and runs fine in Visual Studio 2012 and also from the command line, but when i try running it with the Perf Analyzer it crashes. The profiling method is Sampling. There's not much to go on, it does always seem to crash around roughly the same place, and the best I can tell is there is some Win error reported, something about a buffer overflow.  Has anyone experienced this and have any idea what might be going on?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the profiler.  Try reporting it to microsoft directly.

Comment: I've had crashes with the VS profiler when targetting Any CPU that were fixed by retargeting to x86.

Comment: @JonHarrop: I'd like to try that but unf. Any CPU is the only choice i get in the drop-down list box for Platform

Comment: @JonHarrop: So I did find the option to change the platform under Solution settings, and I tried changing to x64 as i have a 64 bit m/c) but it still crashes. I don't seem to have the option of making it x86

Comment: @JonHarrop I had exactly the same situation, re-targeting to x86 works fine. Typically in this case the app runs much faster in x86 than in x64, which makes me more curious about what's going on (sadly the profiler would crash so that I was unable to figure out the hotspot)